# Stuck with class structure in Windows 8 app development

Tags: class, windows-8, structure, datacontractserializer

Required: I want an XML file to be serialized like this

```
<StudentGroupList>
   <Group key = 1>
      <StudentItem>
           <Name> John </Name>
           <GroupName>1</GroupName>
      <StudentItem>
      <StudentItem>
           <Name> David</Name>
           <GroupName>1</GroupName>
      <StudentItem>
   </Group>
   <Group key = 2>
      <StudentItem>
           <Name> Ron</Name>
           <GroupName>2</GroupName>
      <StudentItem>
   </Group>
 </StudentGroupList>
```

Here is the class structure I created to serialize and deserialize

```
    public class StudentItem
    {
       public string Name {get; set;}
       public  int GroupName {get; set;}
    }

   public  class StudentGroupList
    {
       public List<StudentItem> lstStudnetItem = new List<StudentItem>();
       public int key {get;set;}
    }
    class StudentDataSource
    {
          public  List<StudentGroupList> lstStudnetGroup = new List<StudentGroupList>();   
          //Confusion in below line
           static StudentDataSource objDataSource = new  StudentDataSource();
    }
```

I have created a single instance of `StudentDataSource` so that I can use it globally on every page of my app. I want to use a single instance because this instance will deserialize from the XML file above and simultaneously update it as soon as any changes are made. Now as you see I have made this instance static, I can't access the `lstStudnetGroup`.

Please provide me a solution of class structure so that I can easily create an app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the immediate issue with `lstStudnetGroup` is that it has private access by default.  Add "public" to the declaration and you should be able to see it.  That said, you wouldn't be able to access `objDataSource` either outside of the `StudentDataSource` class.

Does StudentDataSource need to include a static instance of itself?  Wouldn't this suffice:

> class StudentDataSource
>    {
>      public static List lstStudnetGroup = new List();
>    }

then in code you can reference

> StudentDataSource.lstStudnetGroup.XXXX

Comment: i made the changes in code. still it doesn't work.
and obviously how will it work sir, a static object "objDataSource " can't access a non static object "lstStudnetGroup"
any solution to it?

Comment: note that I made lstStudnetGroup static and removed objDataSource altogether, since it wasn't clear to me what purpose that additional member served.

Comment: if u r making "lstStudnetGroup" static then how am i going to access  "lstStudnetItem". I will have to make it static too. and if make it static then i will have to make all property of class "StudentItem" static.

Comment: no, the other classes/properties don't need to be static. Since what you're after is a singleton pattern, take a look at [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) it may help clear things up

Comment: please refer to my question. I have done it as you have asked. but i get an error.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545063/stack-overflow-error-in-singleton-pattern-help-asap